# ReactiveForm element show different <select> value in drag ghost with Dragula

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, dragula, ng2-dragula

When there is an Angular ReactiveForm element inside a dragged element, it shows a changed value in the drag ghost. The element on its final destination shows the correct value again.

Try a [minimum example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-abh5jc?file=src%2Fmain.ts%5D):
When you grab the second element (O2 with value "O2") and drag it, the ghost changes its value to "O1" while being dragged.

Is it wrong to have a form element inside a draggable? If not, is it a bug? In `ng2-dragula` or rather in the (`Reactive`)`FormsModule`?

How could I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that selected `option` element must have `selected` attribute present.

So, you might do this:

add element reference, and also add change listener on `select` element, and then, on change, assign selected value to a variable which will then serve to set `selected` attribute via `attr.selected` in the template:

Try this:

```
<select [formControl]="formControl" (change)="chng($event)" #select>
  <option value="O1" [attr.selected]="selected === 'O1' ? '' : null">O1</option>
  <option value="O2" [attr.selected]="selected === 'O2' ? '' : null">O2</option>
  <option value="O3" [attr.selected]="selected === 'O3' ? '' : null">O3</option>
</select>
```

```
@ViewChild('select') select!: ElementRef<HTMLSelectElement>;

  selected: string = 'O2';

  formControl = new UntypedFormControl('O2');

  // set value for selected attribute
  chng(event: Event) {
    this.selected = (event.target as HTMLOptionElement).value;
  }
```

**[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-owcouj?file=src%2Fmain.ts)**

Comment: Evil hack. It's wonderful! ;-)

Comment: ah, man, it turns out the `attr.selected` didn't work because in the template you had `O2` (letter o), not zero `02`, so that comparison failed, so I went chasing red herrings.. Anyhoo, fixed it now, it can work with angular directive, will update stackblitz later